# How to get radgrid (Telerik) row count in asp.net

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

How to get radgrid (Telerik) row count in asp.net and how to get cell value from Telerik to assign a variable

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)
    {
        GridPagerItem pagerItem = e.Item as GridPagerItem;
        int itemsCount = pagerItem.Paging.DataSourceCount;
        Label1.Text = "Total items count: " + itemsCount;
    }
}
```

For more info check out this thread: https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-total-rows-count-of-radgrid

This article will show you how to access the cells on the server: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/accessing-values-and-controls/server-side/accessing-cells